# How to run or condition in Dust template

Tags: dust.js, dust-helpers

I am using 
`"dustjs-helpers": "1.6.0"`, with `"dustjs-linkedin": "^2.6.0"` .

In my template I need to check an OR condition like

```
if( cherry === true || berry === true)
  path/to/template1/
else 
  path/to/template2/
```

How do I accomplish this with the Dust helpers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you're testing two different variables, you'll need two different truth tests.

You can either put this logic into your template, or into a small helper. I'll show you both ways.

Let's assume that your context looks like this:

```
{
  "cherry": false,
  "berry": true
}
```

### Template method

**This method requires dustjs-helpers >= 1.6.2**

You'll have to include two `{@eq}` checks. Because you're using such an up-to-date version of Dust, you have access to the `{@any}` and `{@none}` helpers.

```
{@select key=cherry}
  {@eq value="true" type="boolean"/}
  {@eq key=berry value="true" type="boolean"/}
  {@any}path/to/template1{/any}
  {@none}path/to/template2{/none}
{/select}
```

You have to manually override the `key` to `berry` in the second truth test.

### Less-Awesome Template Method

Works with all versions of dustjs-helpers.

```
{@eq key=cherry value="true" type="boolean"}
  path/to/template1
  {:else}
  {@eq key=berry value="true" type="boolean"}
  path/to/template1
  {:else}
    path/to/template2
  {/eq}
{/eq}
```

Cons: this doesn't scale, it's ugly, it repeats data.

### Helper method

Doesn't require dustjs-helpers at all.

```
{
  "cherry": false,
  "berry": true,
  "isFruit": function(chunk, context) {
    return context.get("cherry") || context.get("berry");
  }
}

{?isFruit}
  path/to/template1
{:else}
  path/to/template2
{/isFruit}
```

Pros: you can add more conditions without changing your template.

Comment: dustjs-helpers 1.6.2 has been released to make example 1 work.